# Mentioning users in embed

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm currently making a hug command.
Im trying to make my bot mention the the user that used to command and the one that the user mentioned while using the command, my main problem is the bot sends the '@user has hugged @user' outside of the embed,
here is the code that im using

```
const messages = ["https://media.tenor.com/images/c6f27ebfd8657a83794329468c27197f/tenor.gif"]
module.exports = {
    name: 'embed',
    description: "hug embed",
    execute(message, args){
const randomMessage = messages[Math.floor(Math.random() * messages.length)]
const hugged = message.mentions.users.first();
const reply = message.reply(`has hugged! <@${hugged.id}>`);
if(!hugged) return message.reply('please mention who you want to hug');
    let embeddedHug = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setDescription(reply)
      .setImage(randomMessage)
    message.channel.send(embeddedHug);
}
    }
```

Any suggestions why the bot sends it ouside of the embed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not doing it correctly.

`message.reply()` is used to send a normal message and automatically mention the author on the beginning of the message.

This is what you want.

```js
const hugged = message.mentions.users.first();
const embedMessage = `<@!${message.author.id}> has hugged <@!${hugged.id}>`;

let embeddedHug = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setDescription(embedMessage)
      .setImage(randomMessage)
message.channel.send(embeddedHug);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i'm pretty new to this so i'm just trying my best and doing a lot of research before asking on here